# Creating undirected weighted graph with igraph in python

Tags: python, twitter, graph, igraph

I have a data in the text file and I want to create an undirected weighted graph as I read it from the file. Data consists of tweets. For every word in the tweet I create a node in the graph. For every other word I create an edge between them and add 1 to their weight. So the weight of the edge should be the number of occurrences of two words across all tweets.

I create a graph:

```
graph=igraph.Graph();
```

I get edge between two nodes with their using ID:

```
edge=graph.es.select(_source=id1,_target=id2);
```

However this won't find the edge from id2 to id1, even if the graph is undirected. So I used the following hack:

```
edge1=graph.es.select(_source=id1,_target=id2);
edge2=graph.es.select(_source=id2,_target=id1);

if (len(edge1)>len(edge2)):
   edge=edge1;
else:
   edge=edge2;
```

My first question: is there a better way to do this?

However my main problem is updating weights. After I found the edge using the above code I try to update it's weight using:

```
if (len(edge)==0):
   graph.add_edge(id1,id2);
   edge=graph.es.select(_source=id1,_target=id2);
   edge["weight"]=1;
#else add weight
else:
    print edge.attributes();
    print edge["weight"];
    edge["weight"][0]=edge["weight"][0]+1;
```

However I get the following error:

```
 ...
 ['weight']
 [None]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/ivan/workspace/Twitter/process/MovieGraph.py", line 145, in <module>
     processTweet(g,words);
   File "/home/ivan/workspace/Twitter/process/MovieGraph.py", line 87, in processTweet
     edge["weight"][0]=edge["weight"][0]+1;
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I tried to debug, but it looks like the edge exists but the weight is not defined. How is it possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding finding an edge between vertices `id1` and `id2`: using `get_eid` is probably faster because it is implemented entirely in C. You can do something like this:

```
eid = graph.get_eid(source, target)
edge = graph.es[eid]
```

(The second line is needed because `get_eid` returns the ID of the edge only, not the edge itself). `get_eid` also handles undirected graphs properly; in other words, it will always look in both directions for undirected graphs.

However, note that `get_eid` throws an exception if the edge you are looking for does not exist, so you should also catch the exception and add the edge:

```
try:
    eid = graph.get_eid(source, target)
except igraph.InternalError:
    eid = graph.ecount()
    graph.add_edge(source, target, weight=0)
```

The `except` branch makes use of the fact that the ID of a newly added edge will always be equal to the number of edges in the graph *before* the addition, since edges are always numbered consecutively from zero. Note that the call to `add_edge` also sets the value of the `weight` attribute to zero, so you can simply increase the weight after the `try..except` block as follows:

```
edge["weight"] += 1
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you, appreciate the help.